# Where to create the assets folder LibGDX Android Studio

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-studio

I'm creating a game with android studio + libgdx, but it crashes with this logcat:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: bubbles.png
```

I'm following a tutorial, and it says to put the image in the assets folder, which i don't have...

I'm using LibGDX 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In top of your studio select "Project" view, you will have your project structure. Navigate to main directory. If you do not see your assets folder, just right click on main and add a directory named "assets".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See this link for setting up your project: [Using-libgdx-with-intellij-idea: linking-the-asset-directories](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-intellij-idea#linking-the-asset-directories)

Personally, I am a fan of solution 3 and place the assets folder in the root folder next to the core/android/desktop/web project folders.

Answer (score -1):

You can create assets folder under `src/main/`.